# How to run python 3 on Synology NAS

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I'm a little new to linux and I'm having trouble running Python scripts on Synology NAS running on DSM 5.1
I installed a Python 3 module, but when I call

```
python
```

I get

```
...
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan  5 2015, 11:07:22)
...
```

How can I run python 3 ?

Thanks

Comment: Try calling python3 instead of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Geotob the solution is simply calling **python3**